# react native compiling an app from github

Tags: react-native, github, gradle, installation

Helo everyone, i'm new at react native and react. I'm trying to run a project from github, I keep getting this error. I tried many solutions but still getting it.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Taking in consediration that when I start a new project, I can run it without any problem.
Thank you

Comment: It seems some of the configurations of react-native push notifications might be missing in the project. You can open the react-native push notification npm page, and try to ensure the project followed the configurations properly.

Comment: It worked, thank you by running  `npm install --save react-native-push-notification`